# In JMeter and BeanShell, how can I make a variable lowercase?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, lowercase, beanshell

In JMeter's User Parameters, how can I make a variable lowercase?

Left column

```
my_lowercase_variable
```

Right column

```
${__BeanShell('${my_variable}'.toLowerCase())}  //fails
```

or

```
${__javaScript('${my_variable}'.toLowerCase())}  //fails
```

Such that `${my_lowercase_variable}` is lowercase of `${my_variable}`. Tried with quote and without and escaping and such. No luck. Any tricks or tips welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note to self.

It turns out to be a two liner in BeanShell Sampler rather than a __BeanShell command.  Not exactly in the examples unfortunately.

I added the BeanShell Sampler under the Thread Group, then made a variable.  No parameters in the form were required only the two liner script below. As long as I don't change the variable I can copy the data to another variable, change that instead, and then make a Value reference to that wherever needed.

First define a variable in some User Parameters or such 
ie:

```
Name: my_initial_reference 
Value: ITS IN CAPS
```

Add a Bean Sampler under the User Preferences or definition list (just next, it's not a child process)

Put in:

```
String blah = "${my_initial_reference}"; // 
vars.put("blah", blah.toLowerCase());  //${blah} = "its in caps" now available
```

Now under that with Name/Value pairs I can map ${blah} as the value to whatever process name requires it.

Note that the Debug response will still show the initial value in caps but you'll also see blah=its in caps which is what I wanted to use.

Answer (score 3):

Simply can add a function

```
${__lowercase(${VAL},VALUE)}
${__uppercase(${VAL},VALUE)}
```

Note: VAL can be correlated or paramiterized value (e.r VAL= TO LOWER or VAL= TO UPPER). We can use this function in beanshell (pre-processor/post-processor/sampler). Jmeter version using (2.6).

Can use it where ever we want in the script as ${VALUE}.

Comment: Is downloading [the plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#uppercase-and-lowercasesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup) a prerequisite to use this solution?

Answer (score 3):

`${__javaScript('${foobar}'.toLowerCase())}` **does** work. If the output is `${foobar}` instead of `desired value`, it means that the variable has not been declared

Note that variables are defined only **after** the "User Defined Variable" component has been *parsed*. Variables cannot be reused within a single "User Defined Variable" component e.g.:

[image]

The second row in that image will not be able to refer to the variable `my_variable` in the first row. To be able to refer to the first variable, **two** "User Defined Variable" components is needed. The first variable will be in the first component and the second variable in the second one, e.g.:

[image]

With that, `${my_lower_case_variable}` will successfully be converted into `some value`.

---

`${__BeanShell("${my_variable}".toLowerCase())}` works too. (Note that Bean Shell **requires** double quotes. The code in your question uses single quotes.)

Another way is to use [`vars.get`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do):

- `${__javaScript(vars.get('my_variable').toLowerCase())}`
- `${__BeanShell(vars.get("my_variable").toLowerCase())}`

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm, your bean shell code didn't work for me. The bean shell sampler returned:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String blah = AAP;  vars.put("blah", blah.toLowerCase());  //${blah} now availab . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Void initializer
```

I added two double quotes to solve it:

```
String blah = "${my_initial_reference}";
vars.put("blah", blah.toLowerCase());  //${blah} now available
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I had typed it in and not copy/pasted so I had indeed forgotten the quotes as you have described.

Answer (score 0):

The beanshell and JavaScript functions in this use will fail, because they don't import the packages you need in order to use `.toLowerCase`.

If you really need to use a function to convert case (rather then declaring them as lowercase in the first place), you may need to write a full beanshell post-processor script in order to import the needed packages.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript
- http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_examples/org/apache/jmeter/

Comment: actually I was close, the BeanShell Sampler can make a variable.  As long as I don't change it I can copy the data to another variable, the changed one, and then reference that.

Comment: @BlackGaff, What do you mean by "don't import the packages you need in order to use `.toLowerCase`"? (Something like `"str".toLowerCase()` works in both Bean Shell and Javascript without importing anything.)

Answer (score -1):

var blah = "${my_initial_reference}";

blah.toLowerCase();